# In Rust, when implementing the trait `Display`, how to obtain the formatting specified by the caller?

Tags: rust, display, formatter

Given this Rust program, which prints `1.23456`:

```
use std::fmt;
struct Foo(f64);
impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "{}", self.0)
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("{:.2}", Foo(1.23456));
}
```

Which the simplest change to the body of the function `fmt`, to get printed `1.23`?
In general, is there a simple way to use inside the function `fmt` the same formatting options set by the code which prints the object? I know the formatter object has several methods which access formatting options, but is there a simple method to obtain always the same result which is obtained by calling `println!("{:.2}", Foo(1.23456).0);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass *all* formatting options to `.0`, you can just call `.fmt` on it:

```rust
use std::fmt;
struct Foo(f64);
impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.0.fmt(formatter)
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("{:.2}", Foo(1.23456));
}
```

(See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e03de08effc594fd659d2bf553ce1d9a))

Answer (score 1):

Your usecase is actually covered in the [documentation of `Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.precision), the number after the `.` is called the precision and you can pass it like this:

> ```rust
> impl fmt::Display for Foo {
>     fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
>         if let Some(precision) = formatter.precision() {
>             // If we received a precision, we use it.
>             write!(formatter, "Foo({1:.*})", precision, self.0)
>         } else {
>             // Otherwise we default to 2.
>             write!(formatter, "Foo({:.2})", self.0)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Of course you might want to default to a different precision, or not specify one in the `else` branch.

For reference the functions you can use to access different parts of the specified format are:

- [`align`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.align)
- [`alternate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.alternate)
- [`fill`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.fill)
- [`flags`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.flags) (deprecated)
- [`precision`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.precision)
- [`sign_aware_zero_pad`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.sign_aware_zero_pad)
- [`sign_minus`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.sign_minus)
- [`sign_plus`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.sign_plus)
- [`width`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.width)